# "Is there a function to display server data straight to the user interface in swift?"

Tags: swift4

I am working on a proof of concept project and want to display temperature readings that is pulled from a server to the GUI. GET requests displays readings in the terminal, however I would like to do to be able to display this info on the GUI. Not entirely sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic steps in your view controller is:
1. Design your UI using the storyboard. Setup outlets so you can access your controls from code.
2. Make asynchronous API calls using `URLSession` to get data from the server.
3. On the call-back block from your API call, update the UI with whatever data you get. You should update data only on the main queue using `DispatchQueue.main.async`.